# A SQL Query to select certain strings in a folder path

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a column that contains the path to SSIS packages located in a drive. The entire folder path is populated in the column. I need a SQL query to get a section of the string within the folder path.

An example of record in the column_1.

```
/FILE "\"G:\Enterprise_Data\Packages\SSIS_Packages_Source_to_Target_Data_Snowflake.dtsx\""/CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E
```

All I am interested in extracting is the "SSIS_Packages_Source_to_Target_Data_Snowflake". Everything I have tried so far throws errors. The latest code I tried is:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Column_1, LEFT(CHARINDEX('dtsx', Column_1)), LEN(Column_1) - CHARINDEX('dtsx', Column_1)).
```

I would really appreciate some help with this.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Which version of SQL Server are you using?  There is a function called [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) that you might be able to take advantage of.

Comment: Could you please provide more sample data and expected outcome? And could you please explain what logic you want to apply? How should your substring be created? Is the substring always the part between the third backslash and the first dot within the entire string? Or does this differ?

Comment: @Kalu one of the rules of this site is that you never edit a question which invalidates existing answers. If you fail to provide enough information when you first ask it, and someone answers correctly based on what you asked, you should accept that answer and then ask a new question instead of editing the existing question and invalidating the answers provided. This is a technical Q&A site, not a debugging site.

Comment: Also please don't make large bold heading, and learn to use the code formatting option as you can see I edited into your question earlier. For now please take out your edits and put them into a new question.

Comment: Thanks admin for the guidance. I do not see any other section I can post my additional explanations. Since you mentioned I should remove the edit, the only additional option available on this thread is to post it as "Answer your question". Is that what you need me to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible way is this.  not sure on the performance of it though

```
SELECT vt.[value]
FROM (
    VALUES ('/FILE "\"G:\Enterprise_Data\Packages\SSIS_Packages_Source_to_Target_Data_Snowflake.dtsx\""/CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E')
) AS X ([Value])
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(x.Value,'\')
) vt
WHERE vt.[value] LIKE '%.dtsx'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Given you know the extension and its unlikely to appear elsewhere in the string, find it, and truncate to it. Do that in a `CROSS APPLY` so we can use the value multiple times.
2. Then find the nearest slash (using `REVERSE`) and use `SUBSTRING` from there to the end.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(Y.[VALUE], LEN(Y.[VALUE]) - PATINDEX('%\%', REVERSE(Y.[VALUE])) + 2, LEN(Y.[VALUE]))
FROM (
    VALUES ('/FILE "\"G:\Enterprise_Data\Packages\SSIS_Packages_Source_to_Target_Data_Snowflake.dtsx\""/CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E')
) AS X ([Value])
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (SUBSTRING(X.[Value], 1, PATINDEX('%.dtsx%', X.[Value])-1))
) AS Y ([Value]);
```

Returns:

> SSIS_Packages_Source_to_Target_Data_Snowflake

Comment: Thanks @Dale K for your solution. I was able to replicate your answer in my query but not entirely. Please, could you look at the updated info on my initial post. I have tried to explain it more for better understanding.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Dale K for your response and solutions provided. I was able to replicate the same for my query to obtain the result. Below is how I modified the query in my environment to fetch only the new string column1 after applying the string manipulations based on your solution:

SELECT SUBSTRING(Y.column1, LEN(Y.column1) - PATINDEX('%%', REVERSE(Y.column1)) +2, LEN(Y.column1))
FROM (SELECT column1 FROM CTE1) AS X ([column2])
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(X.column2, 1, PATINDEX('%.dtsx%', X.column2)-1) FROM CTE1) AS Y ([column1])

I am actually query a CTE table (CTE1) to get my desired result. The issue is that, I have other columns in the CTE1 that I need to include in the final select query results, which of course should include the string manipulated results from Column1. Currently, I get errors when I try to include other columns in my final result from the CTE1 along with the resultset from the query above.
Example of final query:

Select Jobname,job_step,job_date,job_duration,Column1 (this will be the resultset from the string manipulation)FROM CTE1;

So, what I'm currently doing that is not working is as follows:

```
SELECT C1.Jobname,C1.job_step,C1.job_date,C1.job_duration,Column1 =(SELECT SUBSTRING(Y.column1, LEN(Y.column1) - PATINDEX('%\%', REVERSE(Y.column1)) +2, LEN(Y.column1)) FROM (SELECT column1 FROM CTE1) AS X ([column2]) CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(X.column2, 1, PATINDEX('%.dtsx%', X.column2)-1) FROM CTE1) AS Y ([column1])) FROM CTE1 C1
```

Please, how can I obtain the final results with all the above columns present in the resultsets?
Thank you.

Comment: This is not a new question, this is an answer! Please ask a brand new question, stand alone about the new issue you are facing.